# receive Mail in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, email

is there a way receive an E-Mail in an iOS app, for example to get a notification if an E-Mail on an specified Account comes in?

If no ist is at least possible to read-access the mailstore?

Is there a Lib, to interpret the content of an email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Due to Apple's sandboxing regulations, you cannot access the built-in Mail program's properties from your app.**

You could use a 3rd-party API to connect to a email service (e.x. Gmail) directly through their server, and not Apple's mail program.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the built-in Mail program's settings or properties.

You can, however, make network connections from your app, and could easily use a web service API to check the mail on a remote mailbox.